# Equations in doxygen

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen

I am including amsmath in my doxygen and I wrote:

```
\f{equation}{
  x=2 
\f}
```

but the result in the doxygen is

```
\begin{equation} x=2 \end{equation}
```

rather than the equation

```
x=2
```

Does anyone know what going wrong?

Comment: I used default doxygen setup and have the formula in a C file and works without problems. Which version of doxygen are you using? Which rendering are you using for formulas (LaTeX or MathJax). Are you getting any error messages.

Comment: I am using doxygen version 1.8.8 using LaTeX and I am not getting any errors ...

Comment: Best is to supply a small complete example either here or as a bug report or on the mailing list so it is possible to reproduce. seen the \begin{equation} x=2 \end{equation} it looks a bit like you are using MathJax and don't get it loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, I do that and it works.  The page briefly shows `\begin{equation} x=2 \end{equation}` and then the correct equation appears.

Double check that you have `USE_MATHJAX = YES` in your config file.  The default is `NO`

See: [USE_MATHJAX](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_use_mathjax) in the Doxygen reference.

If not set to `YES` the page displaying the equation might not include the mathjax scripts (I haven't checked):

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
});
</script><script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Comment: @Michael Correct me if I'm wrong but mathjax essentially works as an online service in your html page. Is it possible to make a vanilla Latex equation work with the document instead of mathjax?

Comment: Yes, free online service.  Sorry, don't know :(

Comment: Due to MathJax CDN being out of service, one should set `MATHJAX_RELPATH` to something current, e.g. `MATHJAX_RELPATH = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5`

Answer (score 0):

Instead use

```
\f$ x=2 \f$
```

which would output an inline math formula.

Reference: [Doxygen Including formulas](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html)

Comment: That would work; I'm actually trying to put in a much more complicated equation and putting it inline seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put add some new information to this question as it is 2019 and there is a more easy way to enable MathJax.

When using the Doxygen GUI frontend, You can enable MathJax in the "expert" tab under HTML. By default this will include a CDN. To point to your own downloaded version of MathJax you can set `MATHJAX_RELPATH`.

[image]