# doxygen equations not appearing correctly

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen

I am having some issues with doxygen.  I am trying to include an inline formula:

```
blah blah \f$ x \in [0,1] \f$ blah blah
```

but the html looks like

```
blah blah \( x \in [0,1] \) blah blah
```

Does anyone know why?  If it helps:

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = mathtools amsmath
USE_MATHJAX            = YES
```

Comment: Have you tried placing an empty pair of curly brackets after the \in command? I found when working with MathJax that for some reason *all* the LaTeX commands needed a pair of curly brackets for proper display, regardless of the number of arguments for them. If that fails, you could try escaping the square brackets.

Comment: I don't see a problem withe version 1.8.9.1 (Windows), Default Doxyfile with USE_MATHJAX set and even GENERATE_LATEX disabled. See also the remarks in one of your previous postings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257282/equations-in-doxygen)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have latex installed and verify whether you have these configurations on your Doxygen file:

```
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex #latex command name to be called from terminal
```